# Dynamic Hide Columns Base on User Input

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which lists years across a row 14 with various values that fall below the years. I want to have a user input cell where they can input the number of years they want to see, while hiding the remaining columns. I know the code for this must be simple, but I seem to be having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to actually code this. I have attempted the following:

```
Sub HideCol()

Range("F14").Select

yearSelect = Range("J8").Value

numrows = Selection.Rows.Count
numCols = Selection.Columns.Count

Selection.Resize(numrows + 0, numCols + yearSelect).Select

Selection.EntireColumnHidden = True


End Sub
```

I really think I'm after the inverse of the resize, meaning I'm hiding the selected region versus hiding the rest of the columns. Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, change your year input cell to another column before column F, otherwise, you run the risk of hiding the input cell :)

Then place this code inside the worksheet module where the data is. Make range adjustments to the code as needed for your data.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Me.Range("D8").Address Then 'i moved input cell to D8

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Range("F14:Z14").EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'this range is the total for the number of years you have

        Dim hideYears As Range
        Set hideYears = Me.Range("F14").Offset(0, Target.Value)
        Set hideYears = Range(hideYears, hideYears.End(xlToRight))

        hideYears.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Works beautifulIy. I'm trying to understand the code; What is the "Me" in the code?

Comment: @jules325 `Me` is the object where the code lies, in this case, the worksheet. It's not really needed, but sometimes I use it anyway out of habit of qualifying all objects to their parent.

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it. Thanks,